# Troubles with /p:SignMode=off parameter

Tags: msbuild

I am using github actions and it always tries to sign my driver when building, so I get this error:
my_file_name.inf: error 1284: Class "Sample" is reserved for use by Microsoft

Visual studio also doesn't want to save signmode parameter to proj config

I've tried adding  p:SignMode=Off or p:SignMode=TestSign to the workflow

```
run: msbuild /m /p:SignMode=Off /p:Configuration=${{env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION}} ${{env.SOLUTION_FILE_PATH}}
```

I've tried adding to vcxproj file

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
  <SignMode>Off</SignMode>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In each case it tries to production signing my driver

I've also tried using msbuild locally but /p:SignMode= parameter only changes something when the value is ProductionSign. Off or TestSign not working for me